# MySQLインストール時のエラー

Tags: mysql, windows

MySQLをインストールしようとしています。

途中でエラーが出たのですが、どうすればいいでしょうか

OS: Windows
MySQL 8.0.36

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ログ

```
Beginning configuration step: Writing configuration file

Saving my.ini configuration file...
Saved my.ini configuration file.
Ended configuration step: Writing configuration file

Beginning configuration step: Updating Windows Firewall rules

Adding a Windows Firewall rule for MySQL80 on port 3306.
Attempting to add a Windows Firewall rule with command: netsh.exe advfirewall firewall add rule name="Port 3306" protocol=TCP localport=3306 dir=in action=allow
OK


Successfully added the Windows Firewall rule.
Adding a Windows Firewall rule for MySQL80 on port 33060.
Attempting to add a Windows Firewall rule with command: netsh.exe advfirewall firewall add rule name="Port 33060" protocol=TCP localport=33060 dir=in action=allow
OK


Successfully added the Windows Firewall rule.
Ended configuration step: Updating Windows Firewall rules

Beginning configuration step: Adjusting Windows service

Attempting to grant the required filesystem permissions to the 'NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService' account.
Granted permissions to the data directory.
Adding new service
New service added
Ended configuration step: Adjusting Windows service

Beginning configuration step: Initializing database (may take a long time)

Attempting to run MySQL Server with --initialize-insecure option...
Starting process for MySQL Server 8.0.36...
Starting process with command: D:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="D:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" --console --initialize-insecure=on --lower-case-table-names=1...
D:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.36) initializing of server in progress as process 17748
InnoDB initialization has started.
InnoDB initialization has ended.
root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
Process for mysqld, with ID 17748, was run successfully and exited with code 0.
Successfully started process for MySQL Server 8.0.36.
MySQL Server 8.0.36 intialized the database successfully.
Ended configuration step: Initializing database (may take a long time)

Beginning configuration step: Updating permissions for the data folder and related server files

Attempting to update the permissions for the data folder and related server files...
Inherited permissions have been converted to explicit permissions.
Full control permissions granted to: NETWORK SERVICE.
Full control permissions granted to: Administrators.
Full control permissions granted to: CREATOR OWNER.
Full control permissions granted to: SYSTEM.
Access to the data directory is removed for the users group.
Permissions for the data folder and related server files are updated correctly.
Ended configuration step: Updating permissions for the data folder and related server files

Beginning configuration step: Starting the server

Attempting to start service MySQL80....................
タスクを破棄できるのは、そのタスクが完了状態 (RanToCompletion、Faulted、または Canceled) の場合だけです。
Ended configuration step: Starting the server.
```

Answer (score 1):

インストーラを管理者権限で実行しているかを確認してください。

[2.3 Microsoft Windows に MySQL をインストールする](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/ja/windows-installation.html)

> #### インストールの追加情報
>
> 一般的には、Windows に MySQL をインストールするには管理者権限のアカウントを使用する必要があります。

Comment: 使っているpcのアカウントは1つですし、実行時に管理者確認画面(?)が出ると思います。